# MsBuild Getting propertyvalue inside $([System.IO.Path]::GetFullPath

Tags: msbuild

i am creating a folder in the script executing directory with currentdatetime and pull doown source from source control.

```
<PropertyGroup>
<CurrentDate>$([System.DateTime]::Now.ToString(yyyy-MM-dd-mmss))
     </CurrentDate>
   </PropertyGroup>
```

But when i use the below inside a propertyGroup i do not get the value of $(CurrentDate) it gets escaped.

```
     <FullPath>$([System.IO.Path]::GetFullPath('.\$(CurrentDate)\Build\Service\'))</FullPath>`
```

can any one suggest me what is wrong in the above. Is there any option use the property group value inside $([System.IO.Path])

Comment: Found the cause. Thanks to all..

Comment: Please post your solution so others can benefit from it.